# Mongoose Node Js Join two collections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am new to MEAN Stack and I am developing application using Node Js.

I have two collections say,

```js
var personSchema = Schema({
  _id: Number,
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  stories: {
    type: Array,
    ref: 'Story'
  }
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator: {
    type: Number
  },
  story_id: String,
  fans: [{
    type: Number
  }]
});

var Story = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

In `Person` schema, the `stories` is a list of `story_id` which is an array of values. I need to list out all the persons data with their stories details also.

I have used,
`Person.find().populate("stories");`
But it throws error,

```js
{
  [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed
    for value "26747261"
    at path "_id"
  ]
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "26747261" at path "_id"',
    name: 'CastError',
    kind: 'ObjectId',
    value: 26747261,
    path: '_id',
    reason: undefined
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the CastError is that you are not storing a list of story ids as you intended in the Person schema:

```
 var personSchema = Schema({
   ...
   stories : { type: Array, ref: 'Story' }
 });
```

Instead you should change it to:

```
 var personSchema = Schema({
   ...
   stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
 });
```

Also note the following (from Mongoose's [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) on population)

> ObjectId, Number, String, and Buffer are valid for use as refs.